# isometric homeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be an isometric homeomorphism:
$$(\forall x,y\in\mathbb{C})(d\left(  f(x),f(y)\right) =d(x,y))$$

Let $\Delta$ be a triangle or the interior of a triangle. What is $f(\Delta)$? (are $\Delta$ and $f(\Delta)$ congruent?)

let $d$ be the normal euclidean metric. How if $d$ is only equivalent to the normal euclidean metric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $d$ is the usual Euclidean metric.
Then by the two-dimensional case of Mazur-Ulam Theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur-Ulam_theorem), your function $f$ has to be affine.
So yes, $f(\Delta)$ is a triangle congruent to $\Delta$.

If $d$ is another metric, I doubt you can say much.